# last occurrence of a string in a string in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Is there any inbuild function to find out the last occurrence of a string pattern in a string in  action script .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out the [lastIndexOf](http://www.adobe.ca/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#lastIndexOf()) method of the String object.

PS. If by string pattern you mean a regular expression rather than a literal string, you could use the [match](http://www.adobe.ca/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#match()) method instead, passing a RegExp and setting the `g` (global) flag; then you could check the last match in the returned result.

Comment: thanks..n sry..i was little confused about tht since it searches from right to left .Now i got the logic to use it ..thanks again.